# NodeJS How to proxy multiple clients to the same server

Tags: node.js, proxy

I'm using a proxy server to stream content into my flash client as I cannot get around the crossdomain issues.

Currently I have it working with one client, but if another client requests the same URL, it cannot load the content because it's in use.

Is it possible to have multiple clients connecting to my server and streaming the same resource rather than separate instances of the same resource? This would greatly improve bandwidth usage. Here's my current code:

```
http.createServer(function(req, res)
{    
    //I currently receive req.url in the format /url={URL}
    req.url = req.url.replace("/?url=", "");
    try 
    {
      req.pipe(request(req.url)).pipe(res);
    } 
    catch(e) 
    {
      //For some reason the server errors on favicon but the url requested is flv?
      console.log(":( " + e);
    }
}).listen(8001);
```

So, my question is, is it possible to store the result stream and pipe it to multiple requests?

```
client ---|
          |---- Proxy Server --- External resource
          |
client ---|
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you piping here ?